# How to edit "What's New in Version x.xx" text in appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store

I add new version to my app in the Appstpre. Now it is still "waiting for upload" state.Still I didn't upload a binary.

While I adding new version it ask "What's New in Version x.x" I put some text to it.I want to edit that text or Remove that version.

Is there any way to edit the text that I add to "What's New in Version x.x" or Remove the version that I newly added [It is still "waiting for upload" state.Still I didn't upload a binary.].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app summary, click on "View Details" under the new version. Then click on "Edit" next to "Metadata and Uploads" and simply change the text.